# Replace Ids with respective text values in a row

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a row that provides me values like shown below:

```
ClubbedValues
-----------------------------------------------------
561#557, 562#558, 563#559, 561#560, 562#560
581#578, 581#579, 581#580
561#557, 562#558, 562#559, 563#560
```

I have a master table where I have text values against these id's.  For example:

```
Id     TextValue
-----------------------------------------------------
561    Value1
562    Value2
563    Value3
564    Value4
565    Value5
```

Now I somehow desire the following output:

```
ClubbedValues
-----------------------------------------------------
Value1#Value107, Value2#Value108, Value3#Value109 etc..
```

Where both the text values are mapped somewhere in the master table.

I hope you got the question....

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if you could use a database for a less relational thing of any kind.

Comment: This schema design is really hideous.  You will be much better off redesigning your database in such a way that you can do this with a simple SQL query.  What you ask can be done, but would require so much dynamic SQL and string manipulation that it wouldn't be worthwhile to do, and would probably perform horribly.

Comment: Possible duplicate - different delimiters but several solutions that might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740799/replace-with-wildcard-in-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a table variable and a loop over all values you would need to replace.

```
declare @T table(ClubbedValues varchar(max))
declare @Id int
declare @Value varchar(10)

-- Get the rows from YourTable that you need to process  
insert into @T
select ClubbedValues
from [your table]

select top 1 
  @Value = TextValue,
  @Id = Id
from [master table]
order by Id  

while @@rowcount > 0
begin
  update @T 
    set ClubbedValues = replace(ClubbedValues, cast(@Id as varchar(10)), @Value)

  select top 1 
    @Value = TextValue,
    @Id = Id
  from [master table]
  where Id > @Id
  order by Id  
end

select *
from @T
```