# Recursive SQL UDF for removing non-alpha-numeric characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursive-query

So I'm trying to create my first recursive udf (using MS SQL) to strip anything that's not letters and numbers from a string.

This was inspired by this post ([Replace with wildcard, in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740799/replace-with-wildcard-in-sql))

```
CREATE FUNCTION uf_RemoveNonAlphaNumericChar(
                   @p_CharIndex int,
                   @p_Value Varchar(max) )
    RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @p_CharIndex = PATINDEX('%[^0-9,a-z]%', @p_Value)
    SET @p_Value = STUFF(@p_Value,@p_CharIndex , 1, SPace(0) ) 

    IF @p_CharIndex > 0
      BEGIN
        EXEC @p_Value = uf_RemoveNonAlphaNumericChar @p_CharIndex = @p_CharIndex,
              @p_Value = @p_Value
      END 
    RETURN @p_Value
END
```

This is one step in a bigger problem where I'm trying to split a string that could be `XXX###YYYY` into three parts when some of the parts may be missing.

And I'm trying to do it without a while loop (that solution already exists but runs slow).

if Patindex had a start position (in MS SQL), I would already be done. Of course, it would also not be as much fun. Or as cuss-filled...

Comment: FYI `PATINDEX` can have a start postition: `PATINDEX('%[^0-9,a-z]%', SUBSTRING(@p_Value, 2, 99999))` will start the search at character 2 in the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found yours problem. You removing symbol if even you dont find it ;)
Look at updated answer:

```
CREATEFUNCTION uf_RemoveNonAlphaNumericChar(
                   @p_CharIndex int,
                   @p_Value Varchar(max) )
    RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @p_CharIndex = PATINDEX('%[^0-9,a-z]%', @p_Value)


    IF @p_CharIndex > 0
      BEGIN
        SET @p_Value = STUFF(@p_Value,@p_CharIndex , 1, SPace(0) ) 
        EXEC @p_Value = uf_RemoveNonAlphaNumericChar @p_CharIndex = @p_CharIndex,
              @p_Value = @p_Value
      END 
    RETURN @p_Value
END
```

Answer (score -1):

Does it have to be recursion?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[uf_RemoveNonAlphaNumericChar]
(
    @val varchar(max)
)
RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @s VARCHAR(max), @i INT
    SET @s = @val

    SET @i = PATINDEX('%[^a-z0-9]%', @s)
    WHILE @i > 0
    BEGIN
       SET @s = REPLACE(@s, SUBSTRING(@s, @i, 1), '')
       SELECT @i = PATINDEX('%[^a-z0-9]%', @s)
    END

    RETURN @s

END
```

Comment: The question states that a solution using a while loop already exists and that they are trying to find a solution without using a while loop because it runs slow.

Comment: But using recursiove function will only further slow things down. Performace-wise the best solution will be the SQL CLR one, then this one.

Comment: What i need to do, if I digested my research properly, is modify this function to table-value so I can use it with Cross apply http://sql-sudhir.blogspot.com/2009/10/use-of-function-in-where-clause.html

Comment: CROSS APPLY is just a RBAR with a fancy name. If you need the best performance, for almost anything string-related, use SQL CLR UDF (much less overhead). There's plenty of both samples and ready solutions around.

Comment: I tested the above against the recursive UDF and both returned the same 90173 rows in five seconds every time tested.

Comment: CPU utilization should be higher with recursive solution and might get unnoticed depending on the server load. Use the SQL CLR to see an improvement.

Comment: dean, when you say it's RBAR, the above link, the blogger says when the function is table valued and run with Cross Apply, only one row appears in the profiler. How would i measure this RBAR performance?

Comment: Apples and oranges. The blog you mention uses an inline table-valued UDF, which is nothing more than a parameterized view, and gets optimized as one statement with the outer select (which is good). Your table-valued UDF will not get inlined, but rather executed for each outer row (which is not good).